# ItemsControl items layout like in a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemscontrol

When I use an ItemsControl, items layout looks like that:

[image: ItemsControl]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/861295useOfItemsControls.png))</sub>

As I would like to select items, I thought about using a ListBox, but it then gives me:

[ListBox http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/372874useOfListBox.png](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/372874useOfListBox.png)

The code for ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllFiles, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FolderVM}">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" Height="70" Width="300">
                <DockPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DockPanel.Resources>
                <Image Height="70" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="File Folder"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FileVM}">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" Height="70" Width="300">
                <DockPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DockPanel.Resources>
                <Image Height="70" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SizeFormatted}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

For ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllFiles, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FolderVM}">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" Height="70" Width="300">
                <DockPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DockPanel.Resources>
                
                <Image Height="70" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="File Folder"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FileVM}">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" Height="70" Width="300">
                <DockPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DockPanel.Resources>
                <Image Height="70" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SizeFormatted}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

How can I make a layout like in the first image with ListBox? Tried a lot of things but it's not working.

I could make the WrapPanel have a MaxWidth so it'll stop stack horizontally but I don't feel like it's a good thing.

In your opinion, how can I do this?

Edit: In the first image we don't see all items in the ItemsControl

Answer (score 0):

ListBox automatically books as many space as needed in order to accommodate all elements. In ListBox set

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Lista}" Height="155" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Comment: It may not be clear and I didn't specify it in my original post but in the first image the ItemsControl is scrolling Horizontally (we don't see all items in the image).
Items will stack vertically but Vertical scroll is disabled so it'll scroll horizontally.

Comment: Ok I figured it out: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" in ListBox properties and then bind the WrapPanel MaxHeight in ItemsPanelTemplate with ListBox parent ActualHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out:

- HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" in ListBox properties
- In the ItemsPanelTemplate: bind the MaxHeight of the WrapPanel to the ListBox's parent ActualHeight and Orientation="Vertical" (so it stacks vertically and scroll horizontally).